# Parsing error on trying to retrieve value of a variable extracted using JSON path extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have to assert JSON response of an API. 
So extracted value of a field (state) using JSON path extractor and save it in variable (Optinurl)

"state":"opted_in"

In the Debug Sampler, i see the value of Optinurl as

Optinurl=
[
:   "opted_in"
]

Optinurl_1=opted_in

Optinurl_matchNr=1

When i try to retrieve value of variable Optinurl in Beanshell assertion as below,

String optinValue = ${Optinurl}

i get

ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `String optinValue = '["opted_in"]';'' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 23.  Encountered: "\"" (34), after : "\'[" 
2016/03/07 14:40:15 WARN  - jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`String optinValue = '["opted_in"]';'' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 23.  Encountered: "\"" (34), after : "\'["

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project, I believe you can do what you need via it.
2. The correct ways of initializing a JMeter Variable in Beanshell are:

   - `String optinValue = "${Optinurl}";`

     or
   - `String optinValue = vars.get("Optinurl");`
3. The error you're getting is not connected with your `Optinurl` variable initialization. Looking into

   > Lexical error at line 1, column 23.

   It appears you have some syntax error in the very first script line. So the options are:

   - Double check your code, make sure that parentheses, quotation marks, etc. are matching, statements are ending with semicolon, quotation marks in strings are escaped, etc.
   - Adding `debug();` line as the first line of your script produces comprehensive debug output to STDOUT
   - Surrounding your code into [try/catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) allows to having more informative error stracktraces

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed information on using Beanshell in your JMeter tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to store `[ : "opted_in" ]` into a string variable so use this:

> String optionValue= vars.get("Optinurl");

into your beanshell assertion
and if you want only `opted_in` to store in to a variable then use

> String optionValue= vars.get("Optinurl_1");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitri, Kaushlendra for replying.

I updated my script as below and it is working fine in GUI/command line. Since vars.get("Optinurl") returns ["opted_in"], so had to remove quotes and square brackets before comparing Strings.

```
String optinValue = vars.get("Optinurl"). replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"","");
String expectedState = "${EXPECTED_STATE}";

log.info(optinValue);
log.info(expectedState);

if(!optinValue.equals(expectedState)){
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Values of state field for Campaign id " +  "${CAMPAIGN_ID}" +  " dont match ";
```

}

I could not use String optinValue = vars.get("Optinurl_1") because it fails when i run tests from command line (works fine in GUI mode though)